# Is there a set of data points available to draw an outline of the coast of the British Isles?

Tags: data-request, geospatial, uk, csv

I would like to plot a map of the coastline of the British Isles using gnuplot, for which I need a data set of points along the coast. Is this available in csv form, please, or help to convert it to this format? A low resolution outline is all I need.

Comment: If you can gandle GIS data, see http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/72774 for an answer. CSV will be difficult to get.

Answer (score 2):

Check OpenStreetMaps [Overpass API](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API), which is geared at data consumers.

The outline of British Isles is definitely available in OSM. It boils down to how to extract it from the database.

After some googling I found this page, which lets you [download borders](https://osm.wno-edv-service.de/boundaries/) from OSM. Maybe this is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

The European Environment Agency hosts shape files of European countries.
The British Isles: http://www.eea.europa.eu/data-and-maps/data/eea-reference-grids-2/gis-files/great-britain-shapefile

This online tool converts `.shp` files to `.csv`: https://mygeodata.cloud/converter/shp-to-csv (I haven't tried it)